# Ansible variable assignment from multiple sources

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to learn Ansible by reading code that someone else wrote.  I've run into this:

```
- name: Assign variable
  vars:
    variable: "{{ source1 | source2 | default('default_value') }}"
```

I believe source1 is an extra variable passed when the template is run and source2 is a python function.

How does this evaluate?  Does it combine values from source1 and source2?  Does it short circuit if source1 is not an empty string?

I've found material on code like this `"{{ source1 | default('default_value') }}"`, but it is difficult to find out what happens when multiple sources are chained together.

Comment: This is a jinja2 filter. You can refer to https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-variables-to-be-defined

Answer (score 0):

The expression below doesn't make sense

```yaml
"{{ source1 | source2 | default('default_value') }}"
```

It will return the error

> No filter named ''source2''.. String: {{ source1 | source2 | default(''default_value'') }}

The explanation is simple. The filter [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default)  `return the passed default value if the value is undefined`. This filter can't be applied to a missing filter.